# Get data from a site using js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Assume that there is a website xyz.com where you can write a name and it shows some data as Likes: 40 Videos: 80 etc

Now, Given name as an input to my function, how can I access that website, write a name in it and get the value of likes (40), using javascript?

(For example, my simple js code needs to log "name has x likes!"

Thank you!

I don't really know how to start

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing sounds like a web API. There are many ways we can communicate between servers, like SOAP, REST and GraphQL.

You could take a look at REST APIs, which are a very commonly used type of web API.

In REST, data is formatted as JSON. As an example from your question, you could send something like this:

`GET` `https://api.com/?user=Relys`

and then the response could be something like:

```json
{
  "user": "Relys",
  "likes": 40,
  "videos": 80
}
```

In JavaScript there are also different ways of sending a request. An older way to do is with XMLHTTPRequest, but modern browsers support the Fetch API too.

Here is an example using fetch:

```js
let response = await fetch("https://api.com/?user=Relys")

if (response.ok) {
  let json = await response.json();
  console.log(`${json.name} has ${json.likes} likes!`)
} else {
  alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status)
}
```

Comment: "What you are describing sounds like a web API" — It sounds more like a traditional web page to me.

Comment: "Here is an example using fetch" — That will probably hit a Same Origin Policy error.

Comment: It is a request to a hypothetical external server, as stated in my answer.